# Bubble sort in c language

Tags: c, sorting

I am using following code for selection sort but it always return 0, 0, 0,....

```
#include<stdio.h>


main(){

  int i,j;
  int s=8;
float  temp;
float  a[8] = {99, 80.5, 66, 45, 02, 36, 45, 80};


  for(i=0;i<s;i++){
      for(j=i+1;j<s;j++){
           if(a[i]>a[j]){
               temp=a[i];
              a[i]=a[j];
              a[j]=temp;
           }
      }
  }

  printf("After sorting is: ");
  for(i=0;i<s;i++)
      printf(" %d",a[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

It works fine with int variables but not with float. whats wrong?

Comment: C# and C is not same! I have updated the tags. be careful next time.

Comment: one obvious error is %d instead of %f in the printf format

Comment: You have error in external loop. It should be i < s-1 (but it's not causing errors)

Comment: What are you planning to do, if two values are equal? (Note: `(float)x - float(x)` may not be 0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sorting (I guess its some sort of bubble sort algorithm) seems fine. The output is wrong though, you have to use the `%f` specifier for float values instead of `%d` (which is for integers).

```
 for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        printf(" %f",a[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

problem is with your format specifier in printf().

Use %f instead %d and your problem is fixed.